# "Being a woman is like having chips on your shoulders." Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: idioms

It is a very unconventional use of "have a chip on one's shoulder". Does it make any sense?

Comment: Presumably the coinage in the title "makes sense" to you. And I'm sure most native speakers would understand what you're getting at - that women tend to think they're treated unfairly (with the conventional implication that they are *mistaken* in thinking that). But no native speaker would phrase it like that, even in the unlikely event that they wanted to convey that concept in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What would be a more natural way to phrase it?

Comment: I wasn't aware that "have a chip on one's shoulder" implies that the belief of unfair treatment is wrong. It's not there in the definitions.

Comment: You're mistaken. Here's the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have%20a%20chip%20on%20one%27s%20shoulder#:~:text=Definition%20of%20have%20a%20chip%20on%20one's%20shoulder&text=%3A%20to%20have%20an%20angry%20or,the%20promotion%20he%20was%20expecting.) definition for **have a chip on one's shoulder** (idiom) - *to have an angry or unpleasant attitude or way of behaving **caused by a belief that one has been treated unfairly in the past***. So far as I'm concerned, that highlighted part isn't merely "implied". It's practically a *required* part of the definition.

Comment: (The *implied* part of it is often that a person with a chip on his shoulder is ***mistaken*** in thinking he's been unfairly treated. Maybe he was just ***unlucky***.)

Comment: Yeah. That's what I was saying in my previous comment. I have phrased it really badly though. I was talking about the implication of belief itself being wrong. That part is not heavily implied in the definitions. I couldn't find much about it on other sites either. Both the example sentences in [Know Your Phrase (idk if it's a trustworthy site)](https://knowyourphrase.com/a-chip-on-your-shoulder) make it seem like that the belief doesn't has to be wrong. But the example sentence in Merriam-Webster does implies that the belief is wrong. I'm assuming you are native so I'll take your word for it.

Comment: In nearly all cases, a person with a chip on their shoulder definitely *believes* that they've been "victimised". That "implication" is so strong it's practically *integral* to the definition of the idiom. Assigning numbers here is a bit of a mug's game, but I'd guess over 99% of all usages carry the "victimised" implication. That's over and above the "subjected to bad experience in the past, perhaps just randomly" implication that must ***always*** be present. But even if the ***mistakenly** believes he's been victimised* implication is only there in 90% of cases, it's still usually present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes sense, but it's awkward, it would read more naturally as 'like having a chip on your shoulder' because that is the idiom. We never speak of *chips* (in the plural) *on the shoulder.*